# Numpy - count nonzero elements in 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a soduko board stored as `blocks = np.full(81, fill_value=0 ).reshape((9,3,3))`(*Important note: blocks are indexed sequentially, but to take up less space I show them as a single 9x9 block instead of `9x3x3`; middle block is index 4 (instead of `(1,1)`, bottom left is index 6*).
I want to count the amount of nonzero element in this per block, example:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 5 7 4 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

This has 1 nonzero in block 0 and 3 in block 4. I'm trying to use np.count_nonzero to achieve this, but the return value is never what I want no matter what axis I set as the parameter.
**What I'd like to have as the output is a 9 long 1d array**, but instead I get a `(3,3)` if I use count_nonzero along axis 0, a `(9,3)` along axes 1 and 2. While `axis=2` does contain the value I want they are in different columns. Should I try to extract the values in a 1d array, or is there a way to make this work properly with count_nonzero?

Edit: Just to clarify blocks looks like this:

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [2 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[5 7 4]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
>>> z
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> np.bincount(z.nonzero()[0], minlength=9)
array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: it's very close, but instead of `[1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0]` this returns `[0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0]` for the example array

Comment: @devor yes,  your example array is all zeros for the first row, hence the answer returns 0 nonzero items in the first position

Comment: Scrap my previous comment, it actually does work, my mistake was applying it to the `9x9` representation instead of the `9x(3x3)`

Comment: @devor fair enough, glad it helped you out

Comment: Thanks for the help!